# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting

at first,sorry for my bad english.
i have problem with my hosting,i never touch windows hosting/ASP .NET before,so here the problem.

[image]

### Server Error in '/' Application.

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

---

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
> Umbraco.Web.Runtime.WebRuntime.Boot(IRegister register) +139
> Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplicationBase.HandleApplicationStart(Object sender, EventArgs evargs) +47
> Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplicationBase.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs evargs) +34

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +474
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +219
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +304

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +660
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189

please help me

Comment: I do not believe this to be a JavaScript issue.

Comment: This error means that you have some code that is operating on a type and not on an instance of that type. In other words, you aren't instantiating an object (using `new`) where you should be. The compiler should take you to the exact line where the issue is so you can see what type you need to make an instance of. Looks like it may be the `HttpContext`.

Comment: Also see: [What's a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186#4660186)